# Finding maximum number of factors in n!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, p-adic-number-theory

I am quite new to $v_p()$ problems, and would like to know if anyone prove that $v_n(n!)\le n/2$?

Basically, what I mean is that prove that for all positive integers $n$, the amount of factors of $n$ in $n!$ is always going to be at most $n/2$.

---

> For any integers $n \ge 2$ and $m \ge 1$, define $v_n(m) = \max\{k \in \mathbb{N} : n^k \mid m\}$.
>
> Prove that $v_n(n!) \le \dfrac{n}{2}$ for all integers $n \ge 2$.

Comment: What is a $v_p()$ problem?

Comment: In $v_n$ shouldn't $n$ be prime?

Comment: What does the "largest amount of factors of $n$ in $n!$" mean? A number has a fixed set of factors, what would the largest amount be?

Comment: I think the most likely interpretation of this problem is:
If $x$ is the largest integer such that $n^x|n!$, show that $x\leq\frac{n}{2}$.

Comment: ^Agreed. I added what I think is a more clear statement of the problem. @Jahar Mehru: If that isn't what you intended to ask, feel free to edit it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any prime $p$, we have $v_p(n!) = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{p^k}\right\rfloor \le \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n}{p^k} = \dfrac{n}{p-1}$.

If $n$ is not a power of $2$, then there exists a prime $p \ge 3$ dividing $n$. Since $p \mid n$, we have $v_n(n!) \le v_p(n!) \le \dfrac{n}{p-1} \le \dfrac{n}{2}$.

If $n = 2^m$ for some integer $m \ge 2$, then $v_n(n!) \le \dfrac{v_2(n!)}{m} \le \dfrac{n}{m} \le \dfrac{n}{2}$.

If $n = 2$, we have $v_2(2!) = v_2(2) = 1 = \dfrac{2}{2}$.

Therefore, $v_n(n!) \le \dfrac{n}{2}$ for all integers $n \ge 2$.

Comment: In fact, $\upsilon_n(n!)<\frac{n}{2}$ for all $n\ge 3$, because you can strengthen the first inequality: $\upsilon_p(n!)<\frac{n}{p-1}$.